# difference between "take a flag down" and "get a flag down"

Tags: word-usage

Can anyone tell the difference between these two phrasal verbs above?

1. A soldier took the flag down from the flagpole.
2. A soldier got the flag down from the flagpole.
3. My father took the electric fan from the wall.
4. My father got the electric fan from the wall.

To me, these four sentences look exactly similar in meaning.

In Merriam-Webster Dictionary, the phrasal verb "take down" is used as "disassemble" or "pull to pieces" :Take down the building, take a rifle down.

Is it possible for the phrasal verb "get down" to be used as "disassemble"?

Answer (score 1):

No, "get down" is not normally used to mean "disassemble". And if you look up Merriam-Webster, the *first* meaning given for "take down" is the appropriate one in reference to moving something from a higher position to a lower one:

> **[take down](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20down)**
>   *transitive verb*
>
> 1:  to lower without removing [*took down* his pants]
>   2a :  to pull to pieces [*take down* a building]
>   2b : disassemble [*take* a rifle *down*]
>   3:  to lower the spirit or vanity of
>   4a :  to write down [*took down* some notes]
>   4b :  to record by mechanical means
>
> *intransitive verb*
>   :  to become seized or attacked especially by illness

Regarding "get down" vs "take down", there's almost no difference at all between the two, although to me (as a native speaker), "get" subtly hints at a sense of effort or task, whereas "take" is simply the action.

> [**get**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get)
>   *transitive verb*
>
> 3a :  to seek out and obtain [hoped to *get* dinner at the inn]
>   3b :  to obtain and bring where wanted or needed [*get* a pencil from the desk]

In any case, I would use "get down" and "take down" almost interchangeably.